# Expose a computed field (or external data) to Views

Tags: 7, views, entities

I want to add a virtual field to a "node", its content should be computed  from other fields of this node (with the module of the same name or with a hook) AND it must be usable by Views filter and sorting.

Is this possible (using modules or PHP code) ?

Answer (score 2):

I found answser on this site:
http://barcelona2012.drupaldays.org/sessions/displaying-external-data-fly-views-and-ctools

This simple module give a clear example on how to expose external data (webservice) to a views.

Answer (score 1):

Use the computed field module. The advantage is that the field is saved in the database and can be manipulated by views without performance overhead. The field's value is updated whenever the field is saved.

The code for the computed field should preferrably be placed in your module, not in your database. Use the [computed field hook](http://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/07/30/working-drupal-computed-field-module) - here is a nice ([tutorial](http://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/07/30/working-drupal-computed-field-module)).

[Here](https://drupal.org/node/126522) are some code examples.